# How to render input form based on radio button checked in rails simple form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, radio-button, simple-form

I have two options for a radio button and I want to display an input form based on which radio button is clicked using JQuery. This is the simple form input for my radio buttons

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-1 control-label"></label>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <%= f.input :job_application_type, as: :radio_buttons, collection: [['Apply By Email', 'Email'], ['Apply By Url', 'Url']], :label => "How to apply" %>
 </div>
</div>
```

If the first radio button is checked, I want to display this input

```
<div class="form-group show-job-email" style="display:none">
<label class="col-md-1 control-label"></label>
<div class="col-md-9">
  <%= f.input :job_email, :label => "Job Email" %>
</div>
```

If it's the second radio button, I would like to display this input

```
<div class="form-group show-job-url" style="display:none">
<label class="col-md-1 control-label"></label>
<div class="col-md-9">
  <%= f.input :job_url, :label => "Job Url" %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just bind the `change` event to your radio buttons like so, and add/remove a specific class for your form groups:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="radio"][name="job_application_type"]').change(function() {
      if (this.value == 'Email') {
          $('.form-group.show-job-url').addClass('form-group--inactive');
          $('.form-group.show-job-email').removeClass('form-group--inactive');
      }
      else if (this.value == 'Url') {
          $('.form-group.show-job-url').removeClass('form-group--inactive');
          $('.form-group.show-job-email').addClass('form-group--inactive');
      }
  });
});
```

Remove your stying from form groups and place it under this `form-group--inactive` class in your css file.

```
.form-group--inactive { display: none; }
```

Comment: its not working. This is how i changed the form group   <div class="form-group--inactive { display: none; } show-job-email" >  But now, the two conditional fields are visible and the change fucntion dont work either

Comment: should look like this: `<div class="form-group form-group--inactive show-job-email">`, and the other one the same except for the latest class name

Comment: I have this now   <div class="form-group form-group--inactive show-job-email" >
but no changes. The conditional input fields are still visible and the change function now working. Dont know what i am doing wrong

Comment: and you have added `.form-group--inactive { display: none; }` in your css file?

Comment: i just added it to my css file and the form inputs are hidden now. But the change function does not work. My js file is the same as the answer you provided.

Comment: oops could be my bad, in the second line, wrap your values in double quotes, like so: `$('input[type="radio"][name="job_application_type"]')`. So `radio` and `job_application_type` should be wrapped. (I believe your radio inputs are with name `job_application_type`? inspect the element to be sure)

Comment: i inspected it...the name is    name="job[job_application_type]"                     I dont know if it makes any difference

Comment: it does, then just change `[name=“job_application_type”]` to `[name=“job[job_application_type]”]`

Comment: it is still not working...this is my js file $(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="radio"][name=“job[job_application_type]”]').change(function() {
      if (this.value == 'Email') {
          $('.form-group .show-job-url').addClass('form-group--inactive');
          $('.form-group .show-job-email').removeClass('form-group--inactive');
      }
      else if (this.value == 'Url') {
          $('.form-group .show-job-url').removeClass('form-group--inactive');
          $('.form-group .show-job-email').addClass('form-group--inactive');
      }
  });
});

Comment: can you have a look at the chat room you created? I asked a follow up question. Let me know if its better to ask the question as a new question